# Extracting non-contiguous sets

Tags: ruby

I want to get all non-contiguous sets (i.e. any subset whose elements can't be adjacent in the original set):

```
go([1,2,3,4,5]) => [1],[1,3,5],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2],[2,4],[2,5],[3]
```

I am fairly close with:

```
def go(ns)
  return [[]] if ns == [] || ns == nil
  return [[ns[0]]] if ns.length < 3
  (0..ns.length-1).to_a.map do |i|
    dup = go(ns[i+2..-1])
    dup.map do |a|
      [ns[i]] + a
    end
  end
end
```

This gives:

```
[[[1, [3, 5]], [1, [4]], [1, [5]]], [[2, 4]], [[3, 5]], [[4]], [[5]]]
```

which is close to the right results (misses [1], I just have the concat of the arrays messed up and can't figure out how to flatten them.

Note the elements can be any numbers, they are just unique numbers in no order, they could be for example

```
[35, 40, 100, 54, 13]
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what a noncontiguous set is. You say `go([1,2,3,4,5]) => [1,3,5],[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5]`. What about `[3,5]`? There must be some special rule that excludes it, but I don't see what that rule would be.

Comment: Further to @Matt's comment, why isn't `[1]` included?

Comment: I think these are biggest non-contiguous sets of some sort. `[3,5]` is not included because you may add another element, `[1]`, but it is definitely not clear in the question. Edit: That's not true either, as for `[1..8]` even more are missing, like `[1,3,5,8]`, unless this is due to a mistake

Comment: Fixed the description hopefully, added the missing elements.

Comment: The last sentence and array following that you added changes the problem. That's a no-no, especially after answers have been posted. Moreover, that addition can easily be dealt with. If all combinations of indices (base 1) have been computed, it's a simple matter to map your array to those combinations. For example, if your array were `arr = [2, 15, 7, 8, 4, 3]`, and one combination of base-1 indices were `[1, 3, 6]`, that would map to `[arr[1-1], arr[3-1], arr[6-1]] #=> [2, 7, 3]`. I therefore suggest your remove the last sentence and line that follows.

Answer (score 1):

For a given `n > 1` I have computed an array of all arrays containing one or more integers of the form `[a, ... , b]` where `a >= 1`, `b <= n` and for each adjacent pairs of element `i, j`, `j > i+1`. If `n = 1`, `[[1]]` is returned.

I've done this using recursion. `recurse(m,n)` computes all such arrays whose first element is `m`.

**Code**

```
def doit(n)
  (1..n).reduce([]) { |a,m| a + recurse(m,n) }
end

def recurse(m,n)
  return [[m]] if m >= n-1
  (m+2..n).reduce([[m]]) { |a,p| a + recurse(p,n).map { |b| [m]+b } }
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit 6
  #=> [[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6],
  #    [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6],
  #    [3], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4], [4, 6], [5], [6]]

doit 8
  #=> [[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 8], [1, 3, 6],
  #    [1, 3, 6, 8], [1, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 6, 8],
  #    [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 5], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 6],
  #    [1, 6, 8], [1, 7], [1, 8],
  #    [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 5],
  #    [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 6], [2, 6, 8], [2, 7], [2, 8],
  #    [3], [3, 5], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 6], [3, 6, 8], [3, 7], [3, 8],
  #    [4], [4, 6], [4, 6, 8], [4, 7], [4, 8],
  #    [5], [5, 7], [5, 8],
  #    [6], [6, 8],
  #    [7],
  #    [8]]
```

**Explanation**

I believe the clearest way for me to explain how the recursion works—especially for readers with limited experience using recursion—is to simply execute the code after it has been salted with `puts` statements. I've indented whenever the method calls itself and outdented whenever the method returns.

```
INDENT = 6
@pos = 0
def indent;  @pos += INDENT; @s = ' '*@pos; end
def outdent; @pos -= INDENT; @s = ' '*@pos; end

def doit(n)
  puts "doit: n=#{n}"
  (1..n).reduce([]) do |a,m|
    puts "a=#{a}"
    puts "calling recurse(#{m},#{n})"
    indent
    a + recurse(m,n)
  end
end

def recurse(m,n)
  puts "\n#{@s}entered recurse(#{m},#{n})"
  if m >= n-1
    puts "#{@s}returning #{[[m]]} as m >= n-1\n\n"
    outdent
    return [[m]]
  end
  puts "#{@s}begin reduce"
  a = (m+2..n).reduce([[m]]) do |a,p|
    puts "#{@s}  p=#{p}, a=#{a}"
    puts "#{@s}  calling recurse(#{p},#{n})"
    indent
    arr = recurse(p,n).map { |b| [m]+b }
    puts "#{@s}  back to recurse(#{m},#{n}) from recurse(#{p},#{n})"
    puts "#{@s}  array returned mapped to #{arr}"
    a + arr
  end
  puts "#{@s}return #{a} from recurse(#{m},#{n})\n\n"
  outdent
  a
end
```

```
doit 6

doit: n=6
a=[]
calling recurse(1,6)

      entered recurse(1,6)
      begin reduce
        p=3, a=[[1]]
        calling recurse(3,6)

            entered recurse(3,6)
            begin reduce
              p=5, a=[[3]]
              calling recurse(5,6)

                  entered recurse(5,6)
                  returning [[5]] as m >= n-1

              back to recurse(3,6) from recurse(5,6)
              array returned mapped to [[3, 5]]
              p=6, a=[[3], [3, 5]]
              calling recurse(6,6)

                  entered recurse(6,6)
                  returning [[6]] as m >= n-1
```

```
              back to recurse(3,6) from recurse(6,6)
              array returned mapped to [[3, 6]]
            return [[3], [3, 5], [3, 6]] from recurse(3,6)

        back to recurse(1,6) from recurse(3,6)
        array returned mapped to [[1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6]]
        p=4, a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6]]
        calling recurse(4,6)

            entered recurse(4,6)
            begin reduce
              p=6, a=[[4]]
              calling recurse(6,6)

                  entered recurse(6,6)
                  returning [[6]] as m >= n-1

              back to recurse(4,6) from recurse(6,6)
              array returned mapped to [[4, 6]]
            return [[4], [4, 6]] from recurse(4,6)

        back to recurse(1,6) from recurse(4,6)
        array returned mapped to [[1, 4], [1, 4, 6]]
        p=5, a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6]]
        calling recurse(5,6)

            entered recurse(5,6)
            returning [[5]] as m >= n-1
```

```
        back to recurse(1,6) from recurse(5,6)
        array returned mapped to [[1, 5]]
        p=6, a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5]]
        calling recurse(6,6)

            entered recurse(6,6)
            returning [[6]] as m >= n-1

        back to recurse(1,6) from recurse(6,6)
        array returned mapped to [[1, 6]]
      return [[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5],
        [1, 6]] from recurse(1,6)

a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
calling recurse(2,6)

      entered recurse(2,6)
      begin reduce
        p=4, a=[[2]]
        calling recurse(4,6)
```

```
            entered recurse(4,6)
            begin reduce
              p=6, a=[[4]]
              calling recurse(6,6)

                  entered recurse(6,6)
                  returning [[6]] as m >= n-1

              back to recurse(4,6) from recurse(6,6)
              array returned mapped to [[4, 6]]
            return [[4], [4, 6]] from recurse(4,6)

        back to recurse(2,6) from recurse(4,6)
        array returned mapped to [[2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]
        p=5, a=[[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]
        calling recurse(5,6)

            entered recurse(5,6)
            returning [[5]] as m >= n-1

        back to recurse(2,6) from recurse(5,6)
        array returned mapped to [[2, 5]]
        p=6, a=[[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5]]
        calling recurse(6,6)
```

```
            entered recurse(6,6)
            returning [[6]] as m >= n-1

        back to recurse(2,6) from recurse(6,6)
        array returned mapped to [[2, 6]]
      return [[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6]] from recurse(2,6)

a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6],
   [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6]]
calling recurse(3,6)

      entered recurse(3,6)
      begin reduce
        p=5, a=[[3]]
        calling recurse(5,6)

            entered recurse(5,6)
            returning [[5]] as m >= n-1

        back to recurse(3,6) from recurse(5,6)
        array returned mapped to [[3, 5]]
        p=6, a=[[3], [3, 5]]
        calling recurse(6,6)
```

```
            entered recurse(6,6)
            returning [[6]] as m >= n-1

        back to recurse(3,6) from recurse(6,6)
        array returned mapped to [[3, 6]]
      return [[3], [3, 5], [3, 6]] from recurse(3,6)

a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6], 
   [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
calling recurse(4,6)

      entered recurse(4,6)
      begin reduce
        p=6, a=[[4]]
        calling recurse(6,6)

            entered recurse(6,6)
            returning [[6]] as m >= n-1
```

```
        back to recurse(4,6) from recurse(6,6)
        array returned mapped to [[4, 6]]
      return [[4], [4, 6]] from recurse(4,6)

a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6],
   [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4], [4, 6]]
calling recurse(5,6)

      entered recurse(5,6)
      returning [[5]] as m >= n-1

a=[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6],
   [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4], [4, 6], [5]]
calling recurse(6,6)

      entered recurse(6,6)
      returning [[6]] as m >= n-1

#=> [[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5], [1, 6],
#    [2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4], [4, 6],
#    [5], [6]]
```